# Como usar o reverse apenas em alguns itens no flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Estou querendo montar um conteúdo como esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz dessa forma:

```html
<div class='hFlex layout center start-justified workflow_wrapper nb-border wrap nb-padding-10 around-justified'>
    <div class='left'>i</div>
    <div class='left'>2</div>
    <div class='left'>3</div>
    <div class='bottom'>4</div>
    <div class='right'>s</div>
    <div class='right'>6</div>
    <div class='right'>7</div>
    <div class='bottom'>a</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Mas quando eu não tenho 10 itens, eu não consigo alinhar alguns itens da direita pra esquerda. Por exemplo, se eu deixar apenas 5 itens, fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de deixar alguns itens em especifico, começando da direita pra esquerda dentro do "main axis".

Exemplo:

```html
    <div style='display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 500px;'>
      <div class='comeca_esquerda'>1<div>
      <div class='comeca_esquerda'>2<div>
      <div class='comeca_esquerda'>3<div>
      <div class='comeca_esquerda'>4<div>
    
      <div class='comeca_direita'>5<div>
      <div class='comeca_direita'>6<div>
      <div class='comeca_direita'>7<div>
    </div>
```

CSS até agora:

```css
    .Workflow_Wrapper { width: 550px; height: 200px; }
    .Workflow_Wrapper div { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 10px; width: 90px}
    
    .Workflow_Wrapper div:nth-child(5) { order: 4; }
    .Workflow_Wrapper div:nth-child(6) { order: 3; }
    .Workflow_Wrapper div:nth-child(7) { order: 2; }
    .Workflow_Wrapper div:nth-child(8) { order: 1; }
    
    .Workflow_Wrapper div:nth-child(9) { order: 5; }
    .Workflow_Wrapper div:nth-child(10) { order: 6; }
    
    .left { position: relative; }
    .left::after {
            content: "→";
            display: block;
            height: 29px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 105%;
    }
    
    .bottom { position: relative; }
    .bottom::after {
            content: "↓";
            display: block;
            height: 29px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            bottom: -35px;
            left: 50%;
    }
    
    .right { position: relative; }
    .right::after {
            content: "←";
            display: block;
            height: 29px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 105%;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Você poderia agrupar cada linha dentro de uma `div` e ordená-las separadamente.

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="left">
      <div></div>
      <!-- e assim por diante -->
   </div>
   <div class="right">
      <div></div>
      <!-- e assim por diante -->
   </div>
   <div class="center">
      <div></div>
      <!-- e assim por diante -->
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.container > div { display:flex; }
.left {
   justify-content: flex-start;
}
.right {
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
.center {
   justify-content: center;
}
```